# Calling class constructor later in another class method in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing Class A, and it has a constructor that initializes values. I'm creating an instance of Class A in another Class B like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int value;

    A(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }

    void print_string() {
        std::cout << "talking...";
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A new_a;

    B(int b_value) {
        new_a = A(b_value);
    }

    void print_from_A() {
        new_a.print_string();
    }
};

int main() {
    B b(23);
    b.print_from_A();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I have `syntax` errors with this code, it says `no default constructor exist for class A` . What **I want is**:

**1** to make instance of class A global in class B so other methods in class B can access it.

**2** to initialize values in class A through it's constructor by calling it in, and passing the values through class B

Comment: Please add the text of the error messages to the question. Also, try to only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default constructor for `A`. You should use a [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

```
    B(int b_value): new_a(b_value) {
    }
```

Your constructor

```
    B(int b_value) {
        new_a = A(b_value);
    }
```

tries to default initialize `new_a` and then to assign `A(b_value)` to it. But default initialization is not possible without default constructor. You should always use [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```
    A(int value): value(value) {
    }
```

Comment: okay it worked! thanks. another question though on the side, can I initialize class A values by calling other methods in class B other than the constructor?

Comment: @JohnSall No, initialization of member variables happens in the constructor.